# Translating malloc to c++ with nested structs

Tags: data-structures, malloc

I need to "translate" basic graph algorithms, from C to a  hybrid of C and C++ where I use the new operator .
I need help "translating" the construction of this nested structs that I found on the  yale223 notes. 
I will appreciate any help.

```
struct graph {
    int n;              /* number of vertices */
    int m;              /* number of edges */
    struct successors {
        int d;          /* number of successors */
        int len;        /* number of slots in array */
        int isSorted; /* true if list is already sorted */
        int list[];    /* actual list of successors starts here */
    } *alist[];
};

  g = malloc(sizeof(struct graph) + sizeof(struct successors *) * n);
    assert(g);
```

Comment: _"where I use the new operator"_ You don't. Use the appropriate c++ containers like `std::vector` instead.

Comment: So, `successor` is a variable-size structure? That is, one node could have 2 successors while another node could have 5 successors?

Comment: [What is the correct way of interop'ing with C flexible array members from C++?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43839009)

Comment: *from C to a hybrid of C and C++* -- That code you posted is `C` code.  `C` and `C++` are two different languages.  So it's either you want to dump the code you posted and use valid C++, or keep that as `C`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want, but following might help, using `std::vector`:

```
struct successors {
    std::vector<int> list;    /* actual list of successors starts here */
    // int d; /* number of successors */ // Already stored in vector
    int len;        /* number of slots in array */
    bool isSorted; /* true if list is already sorted */
};

struct graph {
    int n;              /* number of vertices */
    int m;              /* number of edges */
    std::vector<successors> alist;
};
```

Comment: Hi @Jarod42 , I am not allowed to use extra libraries  as vector , basically I need to use C  adding new  and delete.

Comment: @anamvd • `new` and `delete` do not support stretchy structs.  C++ does not support stretchy structs, either (even when malloc'd).  Not sure what C++ does when it has to bridge to C ABI.